# How to prevent Android app data loss during update (random issue)

Tags: android, google-play, data-loss

I'm developing an Android app and have been publishing weekly update for the past 3 years.
From time to time I have users telling me that the app lost all its content after a recent update.
There's no code to remove the app data dynamically in my app and I'm sure that the user didn't uninstall the app and didn't clear the app cache.

I'm guessing that it might be a Play Store bug.
A user told me recently he was using my app (listening to an audio file in the background) while the update occurred. At the end of the audio file the playback stopped. He opened the app to see all his data gone.
Is there a way to prevent play store updates if the app is used (the app locks the database for write access during playback) ?
It's not a major issue. It may affect like 0.01% of the users but I can avoid this issue, please let me know ;)

Comment: I'm hearing the same from our app's users. It's silly that Android would interrupt the process to update it, especially since some apps would lose potentially critical data (as in my case). The only idea I have so far is to update during low-usage times, such as late at night, to reduce the chances of it happening.

Comment: After my last update several user say me same things. My app is a professional app, and they loose client precious data, do you have any update on that problem ?